# Using primes to create unique character mappings for scrambled substring searching

Tags: prime-numbers, pattern-recognition

Problem: given a string needle, and a string haystack determine if there is there an anagram of needle present as a substring of haystack? (Assume case doesn't matter).

One solution is to map the characters a-z to the first $26$ primes $2$-$101$ (we exclude $1$). This way it doesn't matter what order your characters are in, $a\cdot b\cdot c = b\cdot a\cdot c = ...$

The problem is that if your needle is $zzzzzzzzzz = z^{10} = 101^{10}$, that number is already larger than $2^{64}$, the max value of an unsigned long.

To get around this limit you can mod by some large prime and expect a fairly good spread. But I was wondering if there's a way to achieve similar results with addition instead of multiplication.

Obviously you can't do a sequential mapping of primes like you could for multiplication (counter example: $2 + 3 = 5$, all three are prime) but I was wondering if there's a combination of primes (or just numbers in general) that you could pick that would allow you to do addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additive equivalent would be to increment the n-th base b digit when you see the n-th character, with b chosen larger than the largest exponent you expect. So add $b^{25}$ when you see `z`, with $b\ge11$ if you expect some letter might appear 10 times. But $11^{25}>101^{10}$ so this might not be good for your use case!

Comment: for this you could preprocess the needle, counting how many of each character there were, to minimize $b$, right? But yes, I was hoping a solution would exist where the needle string could get much larger (1000 characters plus).

Comment: @pseudosudo: Maybe you should just use an array of 26 `int`s. Extra space is cheap...

Comment: right, but then you have to compare each letter one by one which takes more time

Comment: @pseudosudo: Maybe you can store each in a byte then compare the packed bytes directly. Usually the first word (8 letters on a 64-bit machine) would be different if the whole thing were different, so you wouldn't need too many comparisons on average.

Comment: Alternately, store a hash of all the letters in one machine word. Then almost all the time you'd get the right answer from the first comparison. The "no" answers would always be correct, and you could verify the "yes" answers by comparing the other ceil(26/8) = 4 words.

Comment: The hashing solution is the solution I'd use. It takes m! space to store all of the combinations of letters tho, something I was hoping could be reduced through some math property I didn't know. Doesn't seem to be the case tho.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by m! in this context, but I think 4 machine words (16 bytes) is not unreasonable.

Comment: you have to hash all the anagrams of the needle (needle = m), that's m! permutations, so a hash table of length m!. But yes, you're right, normally the length of m! wouldn't matter. Alternatively if there is probably a hash function that allows you to hash to the same value regardless of the ordering of the letters.

Comment: @pseudosudo: I'm certainly not suggesting that! I'd order them alphabetically, then hash, and do the same with the haystacks. One hash, not m!.